# Auto closing tags in gedit -- can a man dream?

Tags: autocomplete, tags, gedit, auto-close

Top of the morning to y'all.

I recently switched to Debian and I'm finding gedit 3 to be a worthy replacement for notepad++.

I have one complaint though: I can't find a plugin which will close tags for me.

Example:

When I type the following

```
<p>
```

As soon as I type the ending `>`, I want `</p>` to be inserted.

```
<p>_</p>
```

The cursor should remain between the two tags, where I placed the `_` character.

Anything that'll do this for me?

PS: Please resist the urge of telling me to man up and just use vim/emacs :(

Answer (score 1):

maybe try Geany?

Please look at the [Geany snippets video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xCGqOt4C4I&feature=player_embedded).

Comment: Some content would be nice, not all of us can access youtube at work... :(

Answer (score 1):

The gedit plugin ["intelligent text completion"](http://code.google.com/p/gedit-intelligent-text-completion/) inserts the appropriate closing tag at the insertion of "</" just like Macromedia Dreamweaver. This functionality comes close to what you describe.

[(Video)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67OINBPOOis)

Answer (score 1):

It might be beyond your dreams, but there is [Zen coding](https://web.archive.org/web/20170115153757/http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/) out there giving you an intelligent [autocomleting syntax](https://web.archive.org/web/20160417084959/https://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/wiki/ZenHTMLSelectorsEn).
There are two ports for gedit from [fmarcia](https://github.com/fmarcia/zen-coding-gedit) and [mikecrittenden](https://github.com/crittermike/zen-coding-gedit).